# Filter in jQuery array

Tags: jquery

I have a render page. I am getting an array in PHP, which I've converted in JSON.

```
var dataObj = <?php echo json_encode($travellerDetails); ?>
```

> {trip_id: "3", booking_reference: "test123", flight: "3", flight2:
>   "0", dep_date: "2016-12-30"…} {trip_id: "2", booking_reference:
>   "test123", flight: "2", flight2: "0", dep_date: "2016-12-30"…}
>   {trip_id: "4", booking_reference: "test123", flight: "6", flight2:
>   "0", dep_date: "2016-12-30"…}

I want to display these rows firstly in my page but after checked checkbox render page should be filtered.

```
$('.checkbox_check').click(function() {
    var checkbox_values = [];
    $("input[name='airlines[]']:checked").each(function(){
        checkbox_values.push($(this).val());
    });
}
<div>Airlines</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Go Air" name="airlines" class="checkbox_check">Go Air</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Jet Airways" name="airlines" class="checkbox_check">Jet Airways</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="Indigo" name="airlines" class="checkbox_check">Indigo</label>
</div>
```

I want to filter `dataObj` array but if more than one checkbox checked. All checked values in `checkbox_values` array. Filter will be `dataObj.operator1=='Go Air'` or `'Indigo'`;

How to do it using jQuery?

Comment: on what basis should the array be filtered, because `dataobj` array & your checkbox property has nothing in common

Comment: Sorry @dreamweiver I mentioned it in question now.

Comment: Your `json` doesn't contain any values of checkbox referred! Could you update it? I believe the `json` data would be appended to `DOM`. If so, what form it takes? `table`?

Comment: "operator1":"value" is in array, actually array is not showing this. but it is. I array you can see .... it means something is not listed.

Comment: Could you please provide a complete valid json then? and also how you are displaying this data to filter?